# sorting fields from ArrayList in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am using the comparator method and am trying to figure out how to display the fields I have sorted. I need three fields in an ArrayList (Records) displayed by last name.

```
private static void sortRecordsOnLastName()
   {
      Collections.sort(records, Record.LastNameComparator());

   }
    static Comparator<Record> LastNameComparator() {
        return (Record o1, Record o2) -> o1.LastName.compareTo(o2.LastName);
    }
```

The file is a .csv file and my code puts it into an ArrayList. I'm not understanding what the return statement does because nothing displays.
EDIT: I got a display but only [] displays.

```
private static void sortRecordsOnLastName() {
    Collections.sort(records, Record.LastNameComparator());
    System.out.println(records);
```

}

```
FileReader reader;
       try
       {
           reader = new FileReader(fileName);   
           BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
           String commaString = null;  // blank at the beginning

           // Reads a complete line
           commaString = bReader.readLine();  

           // If not last line, add to the record
           while((commaString = bReader.readLine())!=null) {
               Record.add(new Record(commaString));
       }
```

Comment: display the fields, same way you have accessed them...`records` have them all. what else?

Comment: It just displays
[]

Comment: You need to share the code where you try and display it and also the code, where you've initialized it for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When it prints `[]`, the list is just empty. Your problem is not connected to the sorting, but somewhere else.